# ORA-00913: too many values while using case when

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case-when

I have a requirement such that, if one condition is true i should execute on query Q1 if that condition fails, i should execute another query Q2. This queries result is the records of search performed by the user. 
I am using case when statement for if condition, as Q1 and Q2 have more than one column to retrieve, I am getting ORA-00913: too many values . I came to know that case when cannot execute queries with more columns in retrieving data.
Can anyone suggest how to achieve this type requirement.

**Update :**

I cannot give exact query, but can provide pseudo code

```
select case when c1='1' then 
select c1,c2,c3 from table1
else select c1,c2,c3 from table2  end
from table1;
```

**Here iam giving sample data.**

Table1

```
C1      C2     C3
1       null    1
1       2       null
```

Table2

```
C1      C2     C3
1       4       1
1       3       5
2       9       null
```

When i run query you provided, the output will be as below.

```
select
    coalesce(table2.c1, table1.c1) c1,
    coalesce(table2.c2, table1.c2) c2,
    coalesce(table2.c3, table1.c3) c3
from table1
    left outer join table2
       on (your keys here)
           and table1.c1 <> '1' -- This gets table1 if c1 = '1';
```

**Output:**

```
C1    C2    C3
1     4      1
1     2      5
2     9      null
```

But what iam expecting the output is

```
C1    C2    C3
1     null   1
1     2      null
2     9      null
```

Hope i explained clearly.

Comment: Can you share the code you have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `case`, you must return only a single record - not more than 1. To achieve your desired result, I would use a left outer join (assuming you have a way to join table1 to table2), but add your check on table1.c1 into the join condition so that table2 values would only be present if c1 <> '1'

```
select
    coalesce(table2.c1, table1.c1) c1,
    coalesce(table2.c2, table1.c2) c2,
    coalesce(table2.c3, table1.c3) c3
from table1
    left outer join table2
       on (your keys here)
           and table1.c1 <> '1' -- This gets table1 if c1 = '1';
```

This solution assumes table1 and table2 relates. If you can't relate them, then it sounds almost like you can use a union all in which you take all the values from table1 where c1 = '1' and union those to all table2 rows. If necessary, you could only include table2 values if c1 <> '1'.

```
select c1, c2, c3 from table1 where c1 = '1'
union all
select c1, c2, c3 from table2; -- where c1 <> '1' -- if necessary
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your sample data and expected output, please use the second query above:

```
select c1, c2, c3 from table1 where c1 = '1'
union all
select c1, c2, c3 from table2 where c1 <> '1'
```

SQL Fiddle: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/710f0/1/0

Comment: Thanks, i will check this approach and update you soon

Comment: For first query you given, here the selection based on column level not at record level means, if condition is satisfied and one of the column of table1 is null it will display data of column of table2. This is not my requirement, if no data of table1 even after condition satisfied, it should display null and vise versa with respect to table2.

Comment: Please can you suggest me do there any other approach?

Comment: I understand your question as how to get the rows of table1 when table.c1 = '1', or the rows of table2 when table1.c1 <> '1'. I don't understand your concern. I have setup a SQL fiddle (http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/3f731/3/0) of my first query. Can you please tell me what is wrong with this or at the very least based on that sample data explain your expected output?

Comment: I given sample data of my requirement. Please let me know if it is not clear.

Comment: The sample data was very clear and showed the second approach was necessary.  I updated the answer with the final query and SQL Fiddle based on your sample data. Hope that helps!