# Using CASE expression in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a scenario, where if prompt from the user (either 1 or 0)=1 then it has to return values from dual else it has to  return the other table  data

Below query I have tried: but getting an error: too many values

```
with CTE_ACC_FNKEYS AS (
(select 
CASE WHEN 1=1
--@Prompt('Users:','A','Customer\Customer Account\Source System Code',Mono,Free,Not_Persistent,,User:3) is not null
then (select  e,f,g,h  from dual)
else
   (
   SELECT
      a,b,c,d
   FROM
       TABLE ( BI_RPT.GET_ACCOUNTDETAILS( 'ON897451','[SA].[0]') ))

end as b  from dual      
))

select * from CTE_ACC_FNKEYS
```

Comment: Case statement expects to return the same datatype from THEN and ELSE part both. If columns a,b,c,d are of varchar type please cast all 0 as characters. That might be your solution.

Comment: i have tried but still getting the error

Comment: What is the datatype of columns a,b,c,d respectively.

Comment: all where varchar2

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ORA-00913: too many values while using case when](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29069199/ora-00913-too-many-values-while-using-case-when)

Comment: No, here i am checking the condition with Case statement

Comment: The basic point is, You cannot return more than 1 value with case statement. This Syntax is incorrect.

Comment: yes, but to achieve this with any other possible way? please guide me

Comment: You have to put case condition with all 4 columns.

Comment: *"I have a scenario, where if 1=1 then ..."* - but `1=1` is **always true**. I think you have over-redacted your code here. We only know what you tell us of your scenario. We cannot help you if what you tell us is incomplete or inaccurate or incoherent.

Answer (score 0):

You can select only one value as @Ankit Bajpai commented. Like this:

```
with CTE_ACC_FNKEYS AS (
(select 
CASE WHEN 1=1
then (select '0' from dual)
else
   (
   SELECT
      'a'||'b'||'c'||'d'
   FROM
      dual)

end as b  from dual      
))

select * from CTE_ACC_FNKEYS;
```

[Demo.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d170657018094bce0b64caffa8554516) If you will need something other than this please do explain in more details and give some result examples you wish to get. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Your code and your explanation of it seem jumbled, but I think you trying to return different results depending on user input. No doubt there's a good reason why this logic can't be incorporated into BI_RPT.GET_ACCOUNTDETAILS() but solving it with CASE is not the right approach.

One solution would be to write a wrapper function. But the solution closest to your current code would be a UNION.

```
select a, b , c, d
from   TABLE ( BI_RPT.GET_ACCOUNTDETAILS( 'ON897451','[SA].[0]') ))
where &&p_user_input = 0
union
select 0, 0, 0 , 0 -- or whatever is represented by e, f, g, h
from  dual
where &&p_user_input != 0
```